# Showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{-3})}$. (or possibly disprove it)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How can I show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{-3})}$. (or possibly disprove it)?

What I know:

I don't know how to begin if it is the case that they are not isomorphic.

In the case that they are isomorphic:

I can show that they are isomorphic to one another by producing a bijective homomorphism.

I consider $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ however I am having trouble thinking of a mapping for the elements that works.

$a+\sqrt{3}b$ maps to ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your problem is in checking that your map is a homomorphism.

I claim that *no* map $\varphi: \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3}) \to \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ can be a field homomorphism.

For assume such a map existed, then it would have to fix $\mathbb Q$ and we have that $-3 = \varphi(-3) = \varphi(\sqrt{-3} \sqrt{-3}) = \varphi(\sqrt{-3}) \varphi(\sqrt{-3})$ implying that $\varphi(\sqrt{-3}) \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ squares to $-3$ which is a contradiction as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3) \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: I would like to clarify one thing if possible. My book exercise asks to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ are *ring-isomorphic.* I assume that if $\varphi$ is a field homomorphism, then $\varphi$ is also a ring homomorphism since all fields are rings.

Comment: Indeed. A field homomorphism is just a ring homomorphism between fields.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $3 = \phi(3) = \phi((0+\sqrt{3})(0 + \sqrt{3}))$, but:

$-3 = (0 + \sqrt{-3})(0 + \sqrt{-3}) = \phi((0 + \sqrt{3}))\phi((0 + \sqrt{3}))$, so the $\phi$ you exhibited is not a ring-homomorphism.

To put this situation a different way: $x^2 + 3$ splits in one field, but not the other, so how can they be isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

The two are not isomorphic, suppose there is an ring isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$,then $\phi(1)=1, \phi(0)=0$, which implies that $\phi(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$. then since $\sqrt{3}^2-3=0$, we must have $(\phi(\sqrt{3}))^2-3=0$, but there is no solution of $x^2-3=0$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ (every element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is of form $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$, if $b\neq0$, the corresponding minimal polynomial is $(x-a-b\sqrt{-3})(x-a+b\sqrt{-3})$, which has no real root).

Comment: The final claim requires *proof!* $\ \ $

Comment: It would be easier to reverse the roles of the two fields and prove that $x^2+3=0$ has no solution in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see no difference, just as I've added.

Comment: The easier proof that I had in mind is that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$ consists of real numbers, none of which have square equal to $-3$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree that your proof is easy. But I don't it's harder to prove that the only real numbers contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is the rational numbers.